# How can i group lists of dicts based on value

Tags: python, json

how can i group lists of dicts based on value.

I have a list of dicts containg data about yt videos. I want to assing videos and all of its data (there is a lot more than just viewcount) to their channel

This is my current code

```
videos_by_channel = []
channel_data = {}

data = [{
    "channel_name": "Energy Gaz Polska",
    "id": "sD4r3acm2iU",
    "viewCount": "1812"
},
    {
    "channel_name": "Penguin Coders",
    "id": "2-S-PMWJVxM",
    "viewCount": "12556"
}, {
    "channel_name": "Penguin Coders",
    "id": "2-S-PMWJVxM",
    "viewCount": "12556"
}
]

unique_channels = ['Penguin Coders', 'Energy Gaz Polska']

for channel_name in (unique_channels):
    for x in range(len(data)):
        if channel_name in data[x]['channel_name']:
            if (channel_name in channel_data[channel_name].keys()):
                channel_name[channel_name]['videos'][data[x]] = {
                    data[x]['id']: {
                        'views': data[x]['viewCount']
                    }
                }
            else:
                channel_data = {
                    channel_name: {
                        'videos': {
                            data[x]['id']: {
                                'views': data[x]['viewCount']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                videos_by_channel.append(channel_data)
```

My desired output is:

```
{
channel_name:{
    videos:{
        id:{
            viewcount:viewcout,
            },
        id:{
            viewcount:viewcout,
            }
        },
    channel_stats:{
        subs:23,

    }
}
}
```

With current code i get this error
"Exception has occurred: KeyError 'Penguin Coders' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show as desired output doesn't make sense to me. Also, your code is doing a bunch of wacky things and is making the whole thing way more complicated that it needs to be.

You seem to be saying that you want to group videos by their channel.  Here's a simple way to do that:

```
from pprint import pprint

videos_by_channel = {}

data = [{
    "channel_name": "Energy Gaz Polska",
    "id": "sD4r3acm2iU",
    "viewCount": "1812"
},
    {
    "channel_name": "Penguin Coders",
    "id": "2-S-PMWJVxX",
    "viewCount": "12556"
}, {
    "channel_name": "Penguin Coders",
    "id": "2-S-PMWJVxM",
    "viewCount": "12556"
}
]


for video in data:
    channel_name = video['channel_name']
    if channel_name not in videos_by_channel:
        videos_by_channel[channel_name] = []
    videos_by_channel[channel_name].append(video)

pprint(videos_by_channel)
```

Result:

```
{'Energy Gaz Polska': [{'channel_name': 'Energy Gaz Polska',
                        'id': 'sD4r3acm2iU',
                        'viewCount': '1812'}],
 'Penguin Coders': [{'channel_name': 'Penguin Coders',
                     'id': '2-S-PMWJVxM',
                     'viewCount': '12556'},
                    {'channel_name': 'Penguin Coders',
                     'id': '2-S-PMWJVxX',
                     'viewCount': '12556'}]}
```

Note that I didn't start with a list of unique channel names.  It's better to just work from the channel names that come along.  So what I'm doing here is building up a dictionary of lists, where the keys in the dictionary are the channel names, and the lists associated with the keys are the videos for that channel.  This is the most natural way to group a list of data records by one of the fields in that record.

You say that you have lots of other data points besides `viewcount`.  This simpler scheme has the advantage of just wrapping an outer structure around your original data records.  So you don't have to do anything special to bring along extra values in each record.  They're already there because the records in the final result are literally the same structures that were in the incoming data.

UPDATE:

I took another look at what you said you wanted.  I didn't realize at first that you were not providing valid output, but were rather just showing an outline of what you wanted.  I am still not sure that this layout makes as much sense as something simpler, but if it's really what you want, here's the code to get it:

```
videos_by_channel = []
channel_data = {}

for video in data:
    channel_name = video['channel_name']
    if channel_name not in channel_data:
        channel_data[channel_name] = {'videos': {}, 'channel_stats': {'subs': 0}}
    channel_data[channel_name]['videos'][video['id']] = {'viewcount': video['viewCount']}

pprint(channel_data)
```

Result:

```
{'Energy Gaz Polska': {'channel_stats': {'subs': 0},
                       'videos': {'sD4r3acm2iU': {'viewcount': '1812'}}},
 'Penguin Coders': {'channel_stats': {'subs': 0},
                    'videos': {'2-S-PMWJVxM': {'viewcount': '12556'},
                               '2-S-PMWJVxX': {'viewcount': '12556'}}}}
```

You didn't say where you would get the `subs` value in `channel_stats`, so I just put in `0` there.

I changed your data just slightly.  You had the same data twice for the `Penguin Coders` videos.  Because the `id` is being used as a key in a map in the structure you wanted, only one record shows up in the end because you can't have the same key twice in a dictionary.  I changed one of the `id` values slightly just so that they were unique, and you could see that you do then get both of them in your structure.